# Return boolean value from checkbox on HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to collect responses from an HTML field in a way that will create a new object with a series of key/value pairs for each of the form fields. Right now every field is returning a string value. I need help with:

- making the 'pages' field return a number value rather than a string
- making the checkbox return a boolean value 'true' if checked and 'false' if left unchecked

For context: I am trying to create a program that allows the user to fill out a simple form with information about a book (title, author, number of pages and whether they've read it or not (the checkbox)); each book will be a new object in an array, and this will be used to display the books in a "library" on the page where the user can then in the future check/uncheck the checkbox to indicate whether they have read the book or not.

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    const obj = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());

    console.log(obj);
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text">

        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input id="author" name="author" type="text">

        <label for="pages">Pages:</label>
        <input id="pages" name="pages" type="text">

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="checkbox">Check if read:</label>
            <input id="checkboxHidden" value="no" name="checkbox" type="hidden">
            <input id="checkbox" value="yes" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
        </div>

        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am pretty much a beginner at JavaScript so the simplest solution to accomplish this would be most helpful! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things to point out here.

Instead of using `Object.fromEntries(data.entries())`, you should directly initialise an empty object to store the manipulated data. This is because of your specific requirements. You mention converting the 'pages' field to a number and the 'checkbox' to a boolean - it is therefore best practice to start with an empty object, which allows you to manually set each key-value pair after making necessary conversions.

You then should loop through the FormData and manipulate each value as needed. The `For...of` loop allows you to iterate over each entry in the FormData object so that you can apply specific logic depending on the type of the field (`key`).

Using this logic, you can then check if the `key` is 'pages' and then typecast this value to a `number`. This is done using `parseInt()`, which allows a `string` to be parsed as a `number`.

Similarly, you can check if the `key` is 'checkbox'. The checkbox behaviour in HTML forms usually involves sending a value if the box is checked and not send any value if it is unchecked. You need to add some logic to return `true` if the box is checked, and `false` if it is unchecked. The ternary operator checks whether the value is 'yes', and then sets it to `true` - else, it is `false`.

Here is a basic implementation with the above in mind and I hope it helps you:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const data = new FormData(event.target);

    // Create an empty object to store the form values
    let obj = {};

    // Loop through FormData entries
    for (let [key, value] of data.entries()) {
        // If the key is 'pages', convert the value to a number
        if (key === 'pages') {
            obj[key] = parseInt(value);
        }
        // If the key is 'checkbox', convert the value to a boolean
        else if (key === 'checkbox') {
            obj[key] = value === 'yes' ? true : false;
        }
        // For all other fields, store the value as is
        else {
            obj[key] = value;
        }
    }

    console.log(obj);
}

const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your wonderfully detailed explanation and sample code. This worked!

Answer (score 0):

Notice the various `<input>` types there are to implement. One is `type=number`.

In terms of converting `.checked` to boolean (true/false), that's done like below:

[image: HTML Inputs]

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')
checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(e){
  console.log(checkbox.checked);
})
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I ended up using the other user’s suggestion because it was a little easier for me to understand, but I will be saving this as an alternative method to come back to for future use!